# How to read Cucumber feature file from Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I have an automation job (Java, Selenium and Cucumber) on jenkins. I'd like to know if it's possible to store my feature files somewhere on jenkins and configure my java project to read these features there. So doing this everyone who needs to edit the feature file can simple access the jenkins file and edit then, otherwise it would be necessary access the java project, edit the feature and commit and push it to the git repository (too complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you change the features option for @CucumberOptions in your cucumber runner class. Just make it point to a different folder containing the feature files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. Jenkins downloads the code from repo to a slave jenkins node on which the test is executed.  The feature files should be located on this node. The build tool or the configs (Maven/etc) should include the feature file locations in the test phase or the test plugins used. The @CucumberOptions also would then specify these feature files to run for the runner.

Note that @CucumberOptions is checked into the repo so you want to make that as generic as possible and then control the feature files in the jenkins node.